# Matching repeating pattern and ONLY repeating pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a repeating pattern and *only* the repeating pattern. For example:

```
A.
A. B.
A. B. C.
A. B. C. ...
```

But not:

```
Hello A.
Hello A. B.
A. Hello
A. Hello B.
```

I am currently matching the repeating pattern with

```
([A-Z]\.)+
```

I tried matching the preceding words with inverse matching:

```
^((?![A-Za-z0-9]))
```

Alas, to no avail.

Comment: What are you trying to do with last regex?

Comment: So your negative test shows that anything but `A.`, `A. B.`, etc. in the line is a fail. Is there any chance that `A.` can appear in the non-match part of the string, i.e., can `Hello` be `HA.`? Are we able to isolate the match really on a string of specified letters followed by a `.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be understanding you right but it seems that you want to match the entire input. in this case you can use `^` and `$` to match from the beginning to the end of the input.

```
  ^([A-Z]\. ?)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
^([A-Z]\.)( [A-Z]\.)*$
```

I'm not 100% certain I understand your question.

Is

> A. A. A.

An acceptable match or do the characters need to increment?